# How to specify column name to an IF EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, count

It's kind hard to explain, but I'm looking for replace this with IF EXISTS to improve performance:

```
Select ... ,
     IF((SELECT COUNT( t.tab_id ) FROM tabs t WHERE t.marker_id = m.marker_id)>0,1,0) multimedia, ....
FROM markers m
WHERE ....
```

On this query, I would like to have a temporary column called "multimedia" filled by 1 if theres multimedia or 0 if there's not.

This code is executed by PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN Exists(Select 1 FROM tabs t WHERE t.marker_id = m.marker_id)
      THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END multimedia,
  ...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but I'm really trying to avoid the COUNT() function, in order to increase query performance...